# C++11 - templates, friends, decltype & access modifiers

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, private, decltype

What's up guys,

I am trying to overload the addition operator for my math vector class.
My (seemingly logically correct) simplified code is:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Vector2
{
private:
    T       m_data[2];

    template<typename U>
    friend auto operator+(Vector2<T> a, Vector2<U> b) -> Vector2<decltype(a.m_data[0] + b.m_data[0])>
    {
        Vector2<decltype(a.m_data[0] + b.m_data[0])> ret(   a.m_data[0] + b.m_data[0],
                                                            a.m_data[1] + b.m_data[1]   );

        return ret;
    }

public:
    inline Vector2(T x, T y)
    {
        m_data[0] = x;
        m_data[1] = y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Vector2<float>  v1(0.5f, 0.5f);
    Vector2<float>  v2(1, 2);

    v2 + v1; // Line 29

    return 0;
}
```

However, GCC 4.6.1 gave me this:

```
W:\projects\Awesome\BetterStuff\main.cpp||In function 'Vector2<decltype ((a.m_data[0] + b.m_data[0]))> operator+(Vector2<T>, Vector2<U>) [with U = float; T = float; decltype ((a.m_data[0] + b.m_data[0])) = float]':|
W:\projects\Awesome\BetterStuff\main.cpp|5|error: 'float Vector2<float>::m_data [2]' is private|
W:\projects\Awesome\BetterStuff\main.cpp|29|error: within this context|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

And if I changed the second vector to an int vector, it would give me more (similar) errors.

The closest I came to figuring this thing out was finding this interesting page: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48884

But sadly, I couldn't use it for solving my own problem.
I tried GCC 4.6.2 and 4.7.0 but my code didn't compile either.

Changing "private" to "public" indeed solves my problem, but obviously my intention is not to expose m_data;

I just want to define an addition operator that its return type is determined by the template parameters, which from my understanding is, a compile time thing - for each instantiation of the template function, the compiler automatically figures out the return type based on the decltype() there. I mean, in which way main() is trying to access the contents of m_data for one of these vectors?

This whole thing is confusing me, any help would be greatly appreciated.

OK thanks

Comment: If anyone is interested, since I'm using numeric types (which have 0-parameters constructors) as the template parameters for Vector2, I figured I can just replace the old decltype with this: decltype(T() + U()). I am still interested though how come the compiler hates my code.

Comment: Interestingly, decltype(T() + U()) *works* if both v1 and v2 are float (i.e. the same type).  At least it does for 4.7.  It still doesn't for float + int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, GCC is right... The problem was not that Vector2(float) was trying to access Vector(int)'s private members, but that **operator+** (which is only a friend of Vector2(float)) was trying to access Vector2(int)'s private members. So the updated code is:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector2
{
    template<typename U>
    friend class Vector2;

private:
    T       m_data[2];

    template<typename T1, typename U>
    friend auto operator+(Vector2<T1> a, Vector2<U> b) -> Vector2<decltype(a.m_data[0] + b.m_data[0])>;

public:
    inline Vector2(T x, T y)
    {
        m_data[0] = x;
        m_data[1] = y;
    }

    inline Vector2<T>& operator=(const Vector2<T>& vec)
    {
        m_data[0] = vec.m_data[0];
        m_data[1] = vec.m_data[1];
    }
};

template<typename T, typename U>
auto operator+(Vector2<T> a, Vector2<U> b) -> Vector2<decltype(a.m_data[0] + b.m_data[0])>
{
    Vector2<decltype(T() + U())> ret(   a.m_data[0] + b.m_data[0],
                                        a.m_data[1] + b.m_data[1]   );

    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    Vector2<float>  v1(0.5f, 0.5f);
    Vector2<int>    v2(1, 2);

    //Vector2<int>  a = v2 + v1; // Doesn't work
    Vector2<float>  b = v2 + v1; // Works

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Vector2<T>` and `Vector2<U>` are different completely unrelated classes if `T` != `U`. What you are trying to do is the same as having a `class A` access the private members of an unrelated `class B`.

Provide proper accessors for your `Vector2` (perhaps subscript operator), and implement your `operator`s using such public interfaces.

Comment: I understand. I strongly prefer being able to access the private members of the vector class - that's also why I defined my operator as a friend. But I'm adding two Vector2<float>'s, so how is it possible that a Vector<float> can't access another Vector<float>'s private members?

Comment: What's interesting is in his code and error message, both `T` and `U` are floats.  I guess it's a hyper-paranoid compiler?

Comment: Actually, I was using MSVC++ until a couple of days ago. I switched to GCC because of the lack of C++11 features in MSVC++. As far as I know, GCC is pretty solid, am I not right? :)

Comment: @Matan: Yeah, the release versions of GCC are pretty solid.

Answer (score 1):

Put simply: You cannot access private members of another class.  `Vector2<float>` and `Vector2<int>` are *different* classes.  You can fix by adding this to your class

```
template<typename T> friend class Vector2;
```

Which will friend all types of `Vector2`.  Then you can access the privates of another `Vector2`.

Comment: Following K-ballo's answer I tried to add this line to the Vector2 class, but somehow absolutely nothing has changed... Same errors

Comment: @Matan: You should post that last edit an answer and mark it as an answer, since the rest of us were all wrong.

Comment: Yep I'm new here, just wanted to give you some extra reputation for your help, but it does make sense to post my edit as an answer... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a private member in decltype as noted above.
Also, I made the addition operator public.  I don't think that's unreasonable.
I also added coodinate accessors.
This works:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector2
{
private:
    T       m_data[2];
public:
    template<typename U>
    friend auto operator+(Vector2<T> a, Vector2<U> b) -> Vector2<decltype(T() + U())>
    {
        Vector2<decltype(T() + U())> ret( a[0] + b[0],
                                          a[1] + b[1] );

        return ret;
    }
    inline Vector2(T x, T y)
    {
        m_data[0] = x;
        m_data[1] = y;
    }
    inline T operator[](int c) const { return m_data[c]; }
};

int main()
{
    Vector2<float>  v1(0.5f, 0.5f);
    Vector2<int>  v2(1, 2);

    v2 + v1; // Line 29

    return 0;
}
```

assuming T and U have default ctors.

Comment: If you put 'int' for v2 as I suspect you meant to do you get issues of private data again.  I think you need (and want) some public way of getting individual coordinates no?

Comment: Again, there are many ways to solve this problem if I access m_data using a public function, but I'm trying to avoid it. Maybe the operator+ was not a very good example since I'm guessing my actual code for it would be "a += b; return b;". But still, for functions like CrossProduct, I want to be able to access m_data even if it's private.